# sifr not working on internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, sifr

Please have a look here: www.blokeswhobake.co.nz - sifr works great, except it does not want to work with internet explorer.  I have had the same problems on a number of sites.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my sifr in IE problem here.

http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=22987

$.sifr({
    path: 'resources/',
    save: true
});
$('.header').sifr({ font:  'journal', height:  '47', verticalAlign:  'middle'});

The problem was I had a comma after true in the first section of code up there.  IE does not like a comma directly before });  Firefox and Chrome are fine with it, but IE is not.

Answer (score 0):

I works with IE V6 for me.  What version of IE and Flash do you have installed?

Maybe you don't have Flash 6 or higher installed for IE?

Also here's what Mike Davidson's site has to say about support:
*"sIFR works on Mac, Windows, and Linux machines with javascript turned on and Flash 6 or greater. As far as browser support goes, it’s great on all the majors and even some of the minors: PC IE 5+, Safari, Firefox, Opera 7+, Omniweb, and even Konqueror. We estimate this covers over 90% of consumer-grade machines in the world."*

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Flash install is slightly broken and sIFR can't detect it. Uninstalling Flash (follow Adobe's guidelines) and reinstalling it should fix it.